# Using try await with upload requests

Tags: alamofire, swift-concurrency

I am using the following code for multipart data upload

```
let postValue = try await AF.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
        multipartFormData.append("123".data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!, withName: "number1")
        multipartFormData.append("456".data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!, withName: "number2")
        multipartFormData.append("SomeLocation".data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!, withName: "location")
    }, to: "http://httpbin.org/post").uploadProgress { progress in
        debugPrint(progress)
    }.serializingDecodable(PostResponse.self).value
```

the `uploadProgress` is used as a closure in this case which is kind of against the try await. Is there a better way for using it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an `await`able `StreamOf<Progress>` you can use, but you'll need to handle the async stream separately, so it's often most convenient to keep using the closure API.

```swift
let request = AF.upload(...)
Task {
  for await progress in request.uploadProgress() {
    debugPrint(progress)
  }
}
let value = try await request.serializingDecodable(PostResponse.self).value
```

Comment: Why is `StreamOf<Progress>` under a separate `Task`?

Comment: If it wasn't, you'd be stuck on the `for await` until the stream was complete, so the separate `Task` ensures it doesn't block the main stream of execution.